# Define return type for command method in Xamarin Forms & MVVM

Tags: xamarin, mvvm, xamarin.forms

I want to define a return type for a method which is associated with my command which is getting executed on a button click. For example,

On Button click,

```
this.Detail = ViewModel.MasterItemSelectedCommand.Execute(seleteditem);
```

In view model constructor,

```
MasterItemSelectedCommand = new Command<string>(OnMasterItemSelected);
```

After that, my method is like,

```
private Page OnMasterItemSelected(string seleteditem)
{
    switch (seleteditem)
    {
        case "ABC":
            return new TestDrillPageDetail("Test Drill Page Detail 1");

        case "DEF":
            return new TestDrillPageDetail("Test Drill Page Detail 2");

        case "XYZ":
            return new TestDrillPageDetail("Test Drill Page Detail 3");

        default:
            return new TestDrillPageDetail("Test Drill Page Detail 1");
    }
}
```

From this method, i want to return Page object which i can use on button click method. If i use Page instead of void as a return type in this method, then i am getting error like, this method has a wrong return type.

So, is there any way to define the return type for the above method ? Please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The command-structure is not designed to use it like that. But you can just define a public method instead of calling the command manually in code.

Your method:

```
public Page ChangeMasterItem(string selecteditem)
{
    switch (seleteditem)
    {
        case "ABC":
            return new TestDrillPageDetail("Test Drill Page Detail 1");

        // and so on ...
    }
}
```

You can define the command like this:

```
public ICommand MasterItemSelectedCommand => new Command<string>((selecteditem) =>
{
    var mypage = ChangeMasterItem(selecteditem);

    // You can use mypage now if you want
});
```

And on your button click event, just use the method:

```
this.Detail = ViewModel.ChangeMasterItem(seleteditem);
```

Comment: Well, thanks for your solution. But in this case, what's the meaning to define a command. because it's a public method which i am calling directly on button click.

Comment: You don't need the command in this case. I just added it, for the sake of completeness, because you also defined a command in your question. You can also just use the command and set your detail-page in the command-action (then you don't need the button-click-event) or you dont use a command

Comment: I have added command because i want to do it though MVVM way. Now if there is no way to define a return type for that method which is associated with command, then this is a good option which you have suggested.

Comment: But you can use commands. You don't need a return type. Just do the things you want inside the Command-Action. Or did I missunderstood something?

Comment: Yes i need a return type because i have to set "this.Detail" in code behind only, not in VM. And the reason is that i don't want to give any page reference to my VM.